# std::unique_ptr::reset overloads questions

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

From the https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset
members of the primary template, unique_ptr

```
void reset( pointer ptr = pointer() ) noexcept;     (1)     

        
template< class U >
void reset( U ) noexcept;       (2)     
void reset( std::nullptr_t p = nullptr ) noexcept;      (3)
```

For me it seems that for (1) if no parameter is giver then default constructor of the pointer's type will be called. But it should behave as a nullptr, so that the pointer inside unique_ptr will be deleted and it will be set to null, how come?

Explanation for the (2) is

```
2) Behaves the same as the reset member of the primary template, except that it will only participate in overload resolution if either:    
    U is the same type as pointer, or
    pointer is the same type as element_type* and U is a pointer type V* such that V(*)[] is convertible to element_type(*)[].
```

I can't really understand it, can somebody please explain/rephrase?

Answer (score 0):

> For me it seems that for (1) if no parameter is giver then default constructor of the pointer's type will be called. But it should behave as a nullptr, so that the pointer inside unique_ptr will be deleted and it will be set to null, how come?

"*default constructor of the pointer's type*" isn't really a thing - but, yes, the default argument is a zero initialized `T*` which will have the same effect as what you're after. `pointer()` (where `pointer` is a `typedef` for `T*`) will be initialized to `nullptr`.

```
using pointer = foo*;    // example pointer typedef
pointer ptr = pointer(); // initialized to nullptr by default
```

This compares equal to `nullptr` and any resource held will be freed.

The overloads (2) and (3) are for the array specialization, where `U = T[]`.

Comment: I don't really understand how/why pointer() is nullptr?

Comment: @Johy It's the default when initializing a pointer. Perhaps [this](https://godbolt.org/z/cbsv3n) example shows it more clearly.

Comment: thank you. I see now how it works, but still don't really understand why. About using started to read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias, but how is called this usage of pointer()? As it's not default constructor, it's something else?

Comment: Ah, well, it _is_ type construction. Like `int initialized = int();` which would make an `int` with the value `0`.